# Higher derivative of a composite function

Tags: real-analysis

I  find formula to calculated higher derivative of a composite function, if external function is power one: $\dfrac{d^nf^k(x)}{dx^n} (k,n \in N).$
Faa di Bruno's formula is uncomfortablу and hard.
There are formula 10 (page 28) in article of Kudryavtsev in
http://ilib.mccme.ru/djvu/mp1/mp1-1.djvu?djvuopts&page=27.

Are there other  formulas to calculate the  higher derivative of the function degree?

My English is bad. I will be grateful if someone edit this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is

$$ \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x)^k = n! \sum_{\sum_i a_i = n} \prod_{i=1}^k \dfrac{f^{(a_i)}(x)}{a_i!} $$

where the sum is over all $k$-tuples $(a_1, \ldots, a_k)$ of nonnegative integers such that $\sum_i a_i = n$.  For example, if $n=3$ and $k=4$ the possible $4$-tuples are the $4$ permutations of $(0,0,0,3)$, the $6$ permutations of $(0,0,1,2)$, and the $4$ permutations of $(0,1,1,1)$,
leading to

$$ \dfrac{d^3}{dx^3} f(x)^4 =  4 f(x)^3 f'''(x) + 36 f(x)^2 f'(x) f''(x) + 24 f(x) f'(x)^3$$

Comment: You are right. But I have problem in example. I recieve $ \dfrac{d^3}{dx^3} f(x)^4 = 4 f(x)^3 f'''(x) + 3! \cdot 6  \text{(number permutations of (0,0,1,2))}\frac{f(x)}{0!} \cdot \frac{f(x)}{0!}\frac{f'(x)}{1!} \frac{f''(x)}{2!} + 24 f(x) f'(x)^3=  4 f(x)^3 f'''(x) + 18 f(x)^2 f'(x) f''(x) + 24 f(x) f'(x)^3.$ Where is my error?

Comment: There are $12$ pemutations of $(0,0,1,2)$, not $6$