# A formula for higher order derivatives of inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, inverse, inverse-function

The formula for higher order derivatives of compound functions is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918540/higher-derivative-of-a-composite-function) as [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula). Does there exist a similar formula for higher order derivatives of an inverse function, i.e. $D^k(f^{-1}(x))$?
I would be most interested in a non-recursive formula, if such exists. A combinatorial term seems unavoidable.

Related: The first derivative of the inverse function is very well known, and the [second](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249253/second-derivative-of-the-inverse-function) one is also not that difficult to determine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the OP, I add a link to [a paper containing the formula](https://barrel.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_view_main_item_detail&item_id=4885&item_no=1&page_id=13&block_id=135) and [the bibliographic data](http://hdl.handle.net/10252/00005538) (in Japanese).

Answer (score -1):

About for HIGHER ORDER DERIVATIVES OF FUNCTIONS PARAMETRICALLY DEFINED,
See https://barrel.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_view_main_item_detail&item_id=5025&item_no=1&page_id=13&block_id=135